# Problems with sqlite and oci on upgradiing xampp

Tags: php, oracle, apache, sqlite, dll

I've updated my server with xampp 1.8.3-3 and I've started to get 2 errors:

First one:

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()...**

Ok, I've edited php.ini and removed the ";" in:

```
extension=php_oci8.dll
extension=php_oci8_11g.dll
extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
```

But, I started getting this error:

The program can't start because OCI.dll is missing... where can I get this 3 dll's for the new version?

Second error:

I've had the same error with ldap, I've also edited the php.ini and removed ";" in:

```
extension=php_ldap.dll
```

After that, I've copied libsasl.dll from \xampp\php to \xampp\apache\bin .

And I still get this error:

**Fatal error: Class 'SQLiteDatabase' not found in**

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is rather old by now, I will try to answer.

Your PHP installation has all necessary libraries to talk with an Oracle database provider. This is just another set of libraries which talks to the actual Oracle database instance.

You will need an Oracle InstantClient on your system. I think the "basic lite" package should be all you need. Download it, unzip it to you system. Afterward extend your PATH environment variable with the path where you unzipped the files to.

After restarting you web server your PHP installation will be able to find the required libraries.

Best regards